# Methods for determining temporal covariance among many time series?

Tags: python, r, matlab, time-series, covariance

We are trying to quantify synchrony in water chemistry variation among several hundred sites. For each site we have a time-series of concentration.

We'd like to quantify the overall temporal covariance (are concentrations going up and down at the same time) among the sites and are interested in different statistical approaches to to do this.

The different chemistry parameters have very different absolute concentrations (e.g. 1-100 ppm for carbon, 0.001 to 1 ppm for phosphorus) so a relative metric is necessary. [We have done this previously](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/ele.12897) with the mean of pairwise scaled covariances, but there surely is a more elegant method.

We are happy to use R, Pyton, or Matlab. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I'm not a hydrologist or statistician; you might want to repost on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

I look forward to seeing what else this community wants to bring to the table.

When you say mean of pairwise scaled co-variances I assume you are
getting a matrix of results where each element is the mean of the
carbon and phosphorus conveniences.

This matrix can be used for clustering by transforming the range to a distance matrix `[-1,1] -> [+n,0]`. For example you could take you mean of carbon and phosphorus co-variance `|-(1-x)|` so that anti correlated samples (-1) approach a distance of 2 where highly correlated samples (1) will approach 0. You could also take the euclidean distance between the vectors of co-variances.

I have a script [here on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/Krewn/14d9ea0b023323c62e752414364aa8a1) that will produce a specified number of
clusters using Spectral, Agglomerative, or Kmeans clustering on pandas
and sklearn in python.

Also R's `hclust` method (ward hierarchical clustering) produces nice results and jmp has a nice interactive hierarchical cluster view where you can spin the nodes with click buttons.

Verifying that samples cluster together in both co-variance space and physical space validates dependence in the system but what of time and synchrony!?

To attack the timing thing I would perform comparative windowed analysis of synchronous sub sets from your time series(plural). For example if your 2 sites have a year of overlapping data with samples 3 times a day you could calculate the correlation by week for weeks starting at each day jan(1-7), jan(2-7) etc. A distribution fit to your the set of all elements in all time series of co-variances provides p values for the co-variance at given weeks to identify when the carbon and phosphorus levels were significantly co-varying.

Comment: You may wish to include the relevant code from your Gist in the post itself - just paste, select, and press Ctrl+K to format.